# Activity and Fragment Lifecycle callbacks order changed after increasing the version of androidx.fragment:fragment lib

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio-flamingo

My team is doing the necessary modifications in our project to make it compatible with the new stable release of Android Studio Flamingo.

One of those modifications was the upgrade of android navigation lib from "2.3.2" to "2.5.0".

It internally ended up increasing the version of `androidx.fragment:fragment` lib.

After running the project and testing its execution, we realized that the order that the Activity and Fragment Lifecycle callbacks are called has changed.

Before:
1 - Activity::onCreate
2 - Fragment::onViewCreated

After:
1 - Fragment::onViewCreated
2 - Activity::onCreate

This is causing some problems because that order matters in our project.

Was this modification really intended? And if so, do you have any tip on how to adapt the project without "too many workarounds" to that new reality?